# Unexpected output of "this.getClass().getSuperclass()"

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

Consider below two cases

### Case I

I have a simple Java class which has a no-arguments constructor. Below is the code

```
public class TestClassOne {

      public TestClassOne() {
           System.out.println("Parent class of TestClassOne is :" + this.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

Object is the super class of all Java classes. So when I am creating an object of TestClassOne in my main method and run it, it is giving me the **desire output** which is

```
Parent class of TestClassOne is :class java.lang.Object
```

### Case II

Now I have another class, named as TestClassTwo which extends TestClassOne. Below is the code

```
public class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne {
}
```

Now when I am creating object of TestClassTwo in my main method and run it, **TestClassOne's no-arguments constructor is also getting called implicitly as TestClassOne is super class of TestClassTwo** and prints the output in the console. I was expecting the output will be same with the case I. But it is not. The output is

```
Parent class of TestClassOne is :class org.test.TestClassOne
```

Why not the above output is same with Case I ?

Could someone explain me why the outputs are different in Case I and Case II?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Because this is the superclass.

```
public class TestClassOne {
    public TestClassOne() {
        System.out.println("Parent class of TestClassOne is :" + this.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

This class `extends java.lang.Object` (even if it is not explicitly named).

So `this` references to an object of the class `TestClassOne` and the superclass is `java.lang.Object`.

```
public class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne {
}
```

This class `extends TestClassOne`.

So `this` references to an object of the class `TestClassTwo` and the superclass is `TestClassOne`.

For `this` always the current *object* is used and never the class where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getClass()` on `this`. The output is different because:

- In case 1, `this` refers to an instance of `TestClassOne`.
- In case 2, `this` refers to an instance of `TestClassTwo`.